# How to find the duplicate

Tags: c++

/* I have written a code for a simple hangman based on instructions given, I just want to know how to detect the duplicated inputs. For this code, It only detects correct letters and the length

For example:

user input: HAM
H
A
A
HANGMAN! */

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Word to be guessed can be assumed to be at most 20 characters long (including end-of-string null character)
    char HangmanWord[20];

    // Variable to store current guess
    char GuessLetter;
    int count = 0;
    std::cin >> HangmanWord;
    //char guessedletter[strlen(HangmanWord)];
    //int j = 0;
    bool valid = true;

    // Check that input word only consists of uppercase English letters
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(HangmanWord); i++)
    {
        if ((HangmanWord[i] > 'Z') || (HangmanWord[i] < 'A'))
        {
            valid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    while (valid == true)
    {
        std::cin >> GuessLetter; //Takes the Guess letter
        if ((GuessLetter > 'Z') || (GuessLetter < 'A')) //Check that guessed letter is uppercase
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(HangmanWord); i++) //loop to check every letter in word
            {
                if (GuessLetter == HangmanWord[i]) { //if the letter is equal to any letter in the word the count increases
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
                if (i == strlen(HangmanWord) - 1) { //If no letter is equal to any letter in the word the program exits
                    valid = false;
                }
            }

            if (count == strlen(HangmanWord)) { //Checks if all letters were guessed and exits the loop after
                valid = false;
            }

        }
    }
    if (count == strlen(HangmanWord)) { //Checks if all letters were guessed correct to print Hangman
        cout << "HANGMAN!\n";
        valid = false;
    }
```

Comment: Lookup std::set, maybe it has what you need

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect whether a letter has already been input, you can work with ASCII characters being represented by numbers. Assuming we limit ourselves to uppercase letters, `'A'` is 65 and 'Z' is 90.

We can do math with these.  `'A' - 'A'` is `0` and `'C' - 'A'` is `2`.

We also know that arrays are indexed starting from zero.

We can put these things together to create an array of boolean values, and flag them as letters are guessed.

```cpp
std::array<std::bool, 26> already_guessed;
std::fill(already_guess.begin(), already_guessed.end(), false);
```

And we can then check on whether a letter has been guessed by looking it up. Consider, for instance, checking whether `'D'` has been guessed. They should start out false, as nothing has been guessed at the beginning.

```cpp
already_guessed['D' - 'A']
```

If it hasn't, we can mark it as guessed:

```cpp
already_guessed['D' - 'A'] = true
```